# Obj-C: Calculate the standard deviation of an NSArray of NSNumber objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If I have an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects, how do I calculate the standard deviation of the numbers in the array?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming it's safe to process all NSNumbers as double length floats (so you'll lose some precision if you've got some 64 bit integers at extreme ends of the range in there) and I've remembered the formula correctly a first implementation could be:

```
- (NSNumber *)meanOf:(NSArray *)array
{
    double runningTotal = 0.0;

    for(NSNumber *number in array)
    {
        runningTotal += [number doubleValue];
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(runningTotal / [array count])];
}

- (NSNumber *)standardDeviationOf:(NSArray *)array
{
    if(![array count]) return nil;

    double mean = [[self meanOf:array] doubleValue];
    double sumOfSquaredDifferences = 0.0;

    for(NSNumber *number in array)
    {
         double valueOfNumber = [number doubleValue];
         double difference = valueOfNumber - mean;
         sumOfSquaredDifferences += difference * difference;
    }

    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqrt(sumOfSquaredDifferences / [array count])];
}
```

Comment: +1 dang, you beat me to it.  If you need higher precision than a `double`, you could always switch to `NSDecimal`.  It'd be slower, but such is the price of precision. :)

Comment: just don't forget to do sumOfSquaredDifferences / ([array count] - 1) if it's a sample deviation :P

Comment: Why iterate twice? sum(1,n) (Xi - M)^2 == sum(1,n) Xi^2 - (sum(1,n) Xi)^2/n So iterate once accumulating sum & sum of squares. (It's how a calculator does it.) OK its probably a small optimization for small arrays, but for a frequently used stats method... If you're really concerned over precision consult Knuth.

Comment: No reason for the double iteration; yours would definitely be an improvement. For precision, I would assume that in a real application you'd have a better idea of what sort of number you're packing into the NSNumbers and what sort of precision you need out.

Comment: Old answer, but anyway, another refinement: the first iteration can be replaced with: `NSNumber *mean = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];`

Comment: And the second iteration can be replaced with: `NSNumber *stddev = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@stddev.self"];`

Answer (score 25):

You can use `NSExpression` built-in functions.

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:numbers]]];
NSNumber *value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@,", value); // => 2.29128...
```

For more information check the official [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) and this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/).

Comment: Really clever answer!

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Comment: stddev: has accuracy issues when 0 is one of the element in the array. To be correct stddev calculates "Population Standard Deviation" and not sample standard deviation

Comment: This is fine answer! only, I tried both the NSExpression, and the direct calculation (average, then sum squares of differences from average, then variance, then stddev --- all in doubles, but for some reason there is a non-standard-deviation in the result... in my case, (mere 6 numbers) the difference between 1.82 (calculation) and 1.94 (NSExpression). Who to believe?

Answer (score 2):

Here a category for NSArray to facilitate similar tasks, using NSExpression, similar to Tiago's method. You can pass it [any NSExpression that you wish to calculate](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/) as string (colon is added in the function).

```
@interface NSArray (Stats)

- (NSNumber *)calculateStat:(NSString *)stat;

@end

@implementation NSArray (Stats)

- (NSNumber *)calculateStat:(NSString *)stat
{
    NSArray *args = @[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:self]];
    NSString *statFormatted = [stat stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:statFormatted arguments:args];
    return [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
}

@end
```

Use like so:

```
NSNumber *result = [myArray calculateStat:@"stddev"];
```

Comment: nice kinky trick to get NSExpression internal functions "out" to the Array interface. Actually, you could go further, and @dynamic ally add (in runtime) these methods to the NSArray, in a generic manner... so "stddev" would appear as [myArray stddev];

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://warrenseen.com/blog/2006/03/13/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation/) to an algorithm you could use. I don't know of any built-in Objective C statistics libraries, so I would just implement the algorithm myself. The link does it in Java, but it should be easy to convert.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good code on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Objective-C) for this. To go through your NSArray (instead of C array like they have in their example), just use this code along with their implementation of SDAccum:

```
- (double)computeStandardDeviationWithArray:(NSArray *)numberArray
{
    double sd;
    SDAccum *sdacc = [[SDAccum alloc] init];

    for(NSNumber *aNumber in numberArray)
    {
        sd = [sdacc value: [aNumber doubleValue]];
    }

    [sdacc release];
    return sd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version I've used some time ago.

```
NSArray *numbers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:...],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:...],
                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:...], nil];

// Compute array average
int total = 0;
int count = [numbers count];

for (NSNumber *item in numbers) {

    total += [item intValue];
}

double average = 1.0 * total / count;

// Sum difference squares
double diff, diffTotal = 0;

for (NSNumber *item in numbers) {

    diff = [item doubleValue] - average;
    diffTotal += diff * diff;
}

// Set variance (average from total differences)
double variance = diffTotal / count; // -1 if sample std deviation

// Standard Deviation, the square root of variance
double stdDeviation = sqrt(variance);
```