# How can i use the accererometer to check whether the device is stable?

Tags: ios, hardware-acceleration, core-motion

I know how to get the accel data but was wondering if anyone knows of any code samples that would determine whether the ios device is stable (swaying or shaking)

Comment: A stable iOS device will report zero (or very small) values for acceleration.  Write some code.

Comment: @Robert: Don't accelerometers tend to report a constant downward acceleration due to gravity? It would be better to check for change than for small values alone

Comment: @Matti: Ah, so you're right.  The value 1.0 corresponds to the normal acceleration caused by gravity at the Earth’s surface.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the last 30 samples of the accelerometer, get per-component averages (x, y, z) and standard deviation for each. Define how little deviation is "stable".

[Obj-C: Calculate the standard deviation of an NSArray of NSNumber objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889486/obj-c-calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-an-nsarray-of-nsnumber-objects)

That will do. Make 3 arrays, each will have 30(or more or less depening on the time frame you want to compare) nsnumbers. You will get 3 standard deviations. The smaller those numbers are, the less the device is moving. Check that the 3 of them are smaller than any arbitrary amount you want, like 0.1.s

Comment: Thanks. can you explain what you mean by per-component average and how I might get the standard deviation.  I'm trying to determine if an object is swaying in the wind. Thanks.

Comment: Edited and added reference. Some copy pasting and you're done