# How to find the average of a group of NSNumbers from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I have an NSMutableArray of NSNumbers that I have created using this code.

```
if (countMArray == nil) {
        countMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    if ([countMArray count] == 10) {
        [countMArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSNumber *currentX = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x];
    [countMArray addObject:currentX];

    NSLog(@"%@", countMArray);
```

this is how my array looks.

```
2014-05-02 20:34:35.065 MotionGraphs[3721:60b] (
    "0.0292816162109375",
    "0.0315704345703125",
    "0.03271484375",
    "0.030517578125",
    "0.03094482421875",
    "0.0302886962890625",
    "0.03192138671875",
    "0.0306396484375",
    "0.03094482421875",
    "0.02874755859375"
)
```

I would like to find the average of the 10 numbers, I understand the mathematics behind it are simple: add all the values then divide by 10. However, I would like to know the best way to attempt this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889486/obj-c-calculate-the-standard-deviation-of-an-nsarray-of-nsnumber-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply wanted to average all the `countMArray` in the numbers array, you could use [KVC collection operator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

```
NSNumber *average = [countMArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
```

Comment: just got an error, working through it now. **reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0x17822b680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key avg.'
*** First throw call stack:**

Comment: @HurkNburkS small mistake. Just edit with this format `[countMArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];`. Missed `@` before `avg`

Answer (score 1):

You should use if array contains NSNumber

```
NSNumber *average = [countMArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.doubleValue"];
```

But you are having NSStrings, so use this below method

```
-(double)avgOfArray:(NSArray*)array{

    double total=0.0;

    for (NSString *aString in array) {

        total+=[aString doubleValue];

    }

    return ([array count]>0)?(total/[array count]):total;
}
```

Comment: What if the array is empty?